# QGIS Attribute tables and adding fields data to all attribute tables through a lookup from an imported database attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I understand you can add data to a single attribute table in QGIS via the field calculator from a database CSV layer. This allows a lot to be done with a single attribute table. Now this is good if you have added all your features to a single layer. However I would like to add my data before I merge so that if the data changes I don't have to merge and repeat this process.

Is there any way to set the field calculator on more than one attribute table and alter data on those tables depending on the data in them?

I am talking about a power tool that allows you to alter data in all attribute tables based on a look up to a existing table. Has anyone found anything to do this?

I have a database in QGIS which was prepared from an external source . It sits in QGIS nicely. I wanted to access the data from each each feature that has its own fields eventually to put them in one layer, so I can fill in information from the database. I can do this on each layer or feature but wondered if there was a global way to set it on all features without visiting each feature. I have seen a YouTube aid which shows you how to do this on a single layer with multiple features in it but not many single features.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. Can you edit your question and describe a specific example, for example using screenshots.

Comment: Still unclear. Add screenshot